# Install Apache Kylin in custom environment

Tags: kylin

I'm trying to install Apache Kylin in Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed:

- hadoop 3.1.2 in pseudo distributed mode (fs.default.name: hdfs://localhost:9000)
- apache hive 3.1.2 and db derby 10.14.2.0 (config hive use db derby)
- hbase 1.4.10 in pseudo distributed mode (using hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase)

but when i call:

- hbase shell
- hbase(main):001:0> list

get error:

```
ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null

Here is some help for this command:
List all user tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:

  hbase> list
  hbase> list 'abc.*'
  hbase> list 'ns:abc.*'
  hbase> list 'ns:.*'
```

and when i call:

- ssh localhost
- kylin.sh start

get error

```
2019-09-27 09:26:41,029 INFO  [main] client.ZooKeeperRegistry:107 : ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find metadata store by url: kylin_metadata@hbase
    at org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.createResourceStore(ResourceStore.java:99)
    at org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.getStore(ResourceStore.java:111)
    at org.apache.kylin.rest.service.AclTableMigrationTool.checkIfNeedMigrate(AclTableMigrationTool.java:99)
    at org.apache.kylin.tool.AclTableMigrationCLI.main(AclTableMigrationCLI.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.createResourceStore(ResourceStore.java:92)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the location for replica 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:409)
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.HBaseConnection.tableExists(HBaseConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.HBaseConnection.createHTableIfNeeded(HBaseConnection.java:306)
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.HBaseResourceStore.createHTableIfNeeded(HBaseResourceStore.java:114)
    at org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.HBaseResourceStore.<init>(HBaseResourceStore.java:88)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop has a long history and it is complex, so we recommend you to use some well-tested Hadoop Distribution such as CDH and HDP, but not a custom Hadoop environment.
   If you are do a PoC and want to learn Kylin quickly, please use Docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone. If want to use Kylin in a more formal Hadoop environment, could you please use a CDH 5.x or HDP 2.x Hadoop Distribution?
   If you have more question, please contact Kylin community by user mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, obviously your HBase is not running; Please make sure HBase is good.